# Android Silent Push

Tags: android, service, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, background-service

I am new to android and I'm playing around trying some features here and there.
I wanted to know what is the way to use silent push - meaning get a push notification on the device without any alarm, notification or vibration - i.e. without the user to be aware of it.
If someone have a tutorial he can refer me to I'll be more than gratefull.

Comment: The notification will popup only as long as the `title` and `message` fields are present in your payload. Otherwise, the notification will be completely silent, it took me a while to realize this.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The default push in Android (Google Cloud Messaging for Android) is a silent push.
You actually have to write code in order for the push notification to generate a notification, sound or any other effect noticeable by the user.

Read the [GCM Guide](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html).

Comment: the document is deprecated